# Detect multiple periods in Regex and kill entire match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to detect a price in regex with this:

```
^\-?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?
```

This covers:

12

12.5

12.50

12,500

12,500.00

But if I pass it

12..50 or 12.5.0 or 12.0.

it still returns a match on the 12 . I want it to negate the entire string and return no match at all if there is more than one period in the entire string.

I've been trying to get my head around negative lookaheads for an hour and have searched on Stack Overflow but can't seem to find the right answer. How do I do this?

Comment: You've got a begin anchor (`^`), why not an end anchor (`$`) too?  That will solve your problem.

Comment: So simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for, is this:

```
^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

What it does:

```
^            Start of Line
\d+          one or more Digits followed by
(,\d{3})*    zero, one or more times a , followed by three Digits followed by
(\.\d{1,2})? one or zero . followed by one or two Digits followed by
$            End of Line
```

This will only match valid Prices. The Comma (,) is not obligatory in this Regex, but it will be matched.

Look here: http://www.regextester.com/?fam=98001

If you work with Prices and want to store them in a Database I recommend saving them as INT. So 1,234,56 becomes 123456 or 1,234 becomes 123400. After you matched the valid price, all you have to do is to remove the ,s, split the Value by the Dot, and fill the Value of [1] with str_pad() (STR_PAD_RIGHT) with Zeros. This makes Calculations easier, in special when you work with Javascript or other different Languages.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. I like the way this deals with my commas and enforces groups of three. Neat and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex:

```
^\-?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?
```

**Note**: The regex you provided does not seem to work for `12` (without "`.`"). Since you didn't add a quantifier after `\.`, it tries to match that pattern literally (`.`).

While there are multiple ways to solve this and the most "correct" answer will depend on your specific requirements, here's a regex that will **not** match `12..1`, but will match `12.1`:

```
(^\-?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?(?:\.[0-9]+))+
```

I surrounded the entire regex you provided in a capturing group `(...)`, and added a *one or more* quantifier `+` at the end, so that the entire regex will fail if it does not satisfy that pattern.

Also (this may or may not be what you want), I modified the inner groups into non-capturing groups `(?: ... )` so that it does not return unnecessary groups.

This site offers a deconstruction of regexes and explains them:

For the regex provided: https://regex101.com/r/EDimzu/2

Unit tests: https://regex101.com/r/EDimzu/2/tests (Note the `12` one's failure for multiple languages).

Comment: Thanks Bianca, nice answer. You've introduced me to non-capturing groups, which I need to go read up on.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit it by requiring there is only 0 or 1 periods like this:

`^[0-9,]+[\.]{0,1}?[0-9,]+$`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aurielle, much appreciated!